# C# on program close

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a project that requires that I run some code when the application closes. The application is only a single form that hides itself almost immediately after execution, so the only way it can be closed is by manually terminating it with the task manager.

If I use the onclose event, will it be called in this case? Also, can someone post a brief code example for setting up the onclose event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea - I got dinged when my windows(less) app didn't shut down with a system shutdown request (you know "terminate this process" type dialog message). You can subscribe to specific requests, for example:

SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_Shutdown);

and the shutdown handler does a clean up (your app) and shutdown:

Application.Exit();

Maybe BFee's has a better answer.

Comment: I actually like this a little better. Do you mean ApplicationExit, BTW? There is no Application.Exit, but there is Application.ApplicationExit

Comment: Microsoft does list an Application.Exit() in short "Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed."

Answer (score 5):

In your Program.cs before showing the form add this:

```
Application.Exit += ....
```